# Are Congressional calls for Barr to resign tantamount to obstruction of justice?

Tags: united-states, obstruction

A number of members of the US Congress have stated the opinion that the fact that President Trump twitted his opinion of Muller's investigation, before it concluded, amounted to an obstruction of justice.  The purported basis for this was that he was a potential future subject of the investigation.

Attorney General Barr stated, during a *previous* Congressional testimony, that he intended to pursue an **investigation** of the *genesis of the collusion allegation* against the President.

After yesterday's Congressional testimony, a number of Congressmen twitted that Barr should resign.  As potential subjects of Barr's investigation into the origins of the genesis of the collusion allegation, did these Congressmen not commit obstruction of justice with their twits?

Specifically, "[Whoever knowingly **uses intimidation**,... or corruptly persuades another person, or attempts to do so, or engages in misleading conduct toward another person, **with intent to hinder**, delay, or **prevent the communication to a law enforcement officer** or judge...of information relating to the commission or **possible commission** of a Federal offense shall be fined under this title or imprisoned...](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1512)"

It seems to me that either both Trump and anyone demanding that Barr resign committed obstruction or none of them did.

Am I missing something?  Or this outside of the purview of the law and the discussion is completely political?

Comment: I see that there is a lot of downvotes without suggestions how the question can be improved.  It must be assumed that all those downvoting agree that it is obstruction, for potential subjects of the investigation, to call for Barr to resign, but the downvoters want this obstruction to happen without anyone asking questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

### No

"Obstruction of Justice" is defined in [Title 18, Part I, Chapter 73](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-73) of the US Code and consist of 22 separate offences. Without going into the details, the actions described do not meet the criteria for any of them.

For example, [§ 1503. Influencing or injuring officer or juror generally](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1503), requires:

> ... corruptly, or by threats or force, or by any threatening letter or communication, endeavors to influence, intimidate, or impede any ...

This is a high bar - it requires offering bribes (corruptly) or threats. Saying someone is unfit for their job and should resign doesn't meet that bar.

This is entirely political hyperbole.

Comment: Unless it's done "corruptly", right?If they are potential subjects of an investigation by Barr, it's as corrupt for them to comment on his fitness as it is for Trump to comment on the legitimacy of Muller's probe, isn't it?[Whoever knowingly...corruptly persuades another person, or attempts to do so, or engages in misleading conduct toward another person, with **intent to hinder**, delay, or prevent the communication to a law enforcement officer or judge...of information relating to the commission or **possible commission** of a Federal offense](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1512)

Comment: @grovkin that’s not what “corruptly” means - it means by offering an inducement (bribe) to the official

Comment: Then how is *by means of corruption* different from 1510(a), where "by means of bribery" is mentioned explicitly?

Comment: @grovkin what a good question! It’s a pity there isn’t a site where you can ask the legal difference between bribery and corruption ...

Comment: But such a question would be about *your claims* about the law rather than about the law.  You are the one saying that corruption in 1512(b) (ie, "corruptly persuades") *really* says "bribes".  Even though the law clearly uses "by means of bribery" in 1510(a) when it means to say "bribery'.  I can't ask a question on this site about your particular interpretation of the law.  If you have a reason for saying both of these formulations mean the same thing and yet both are used, please, explain.

Comment: @grovkin no, I’m saying bribes are an example of corruption